# InkWell and GestureDetector, how to make them work?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to use a GestureDetector for it's onTapDown callback but also have a nice InkWell splash effect.

Is it possible to use these two together?

Comment: I know I'm a little late to the party, but I had the same issue. I ended up to use the InkWell widget directly. Under the hood it returns a GestureDetector as well. In my widget I made a constructor which accepts a VoidCallback onTap. Within the InkWell onTap-Event I just call this provided callback.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to unconditionally handle the pointer down event with no [gesture disambiguation](https://flutter.io/gestures/#gesture-disambiguation), you can make the InkWell a child of a Listener, and set the onPointerDown handler.

For example:

```
new Listener(
  onPointerDown: (e) { print('onPointerDown'); },
  child: new InkWell(
    child: new Text('Tap me'),
    onTap: () { print('onTap'); }
  ),
),
```

It might make sense to add an onTapDown handler to InkWell.

Answer (score 10):

You can pass a [`HitTestBehavior`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/HitTestBehavior-class.html) to `GestureDetector` to make it "non-blocking" by setting the value to "translucent"

Or you can also trigger it yourself using `Material.of(context)`

Answer (score 2):

InkWell uses a GestureDetector under it's hood:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/79b5e5bc8af7d9df3374dfe6141653848d1c03ac/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_well.dart#L560

The reason why a GestureDetector isn't able to work well if the InkWell-Widget is, that it sets the behavior on it's internal GestureDetector to "HitTestBehavior.opaque". This prevents "event bubbling" / event capturing on parent widgets (if my understanding is correct). And because the "behavior" is final, we can't change / fix that by our own.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/79b5e5bc8af7d9df3374dfe6141653848d1c03ac/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_well.dart#L566

As I mentioned in a comment above, I wrapped the InkWell within a widget (which handles other stuff too) and provided a way to pass a callback into it which is executed on the desired event.

**This is my example solution**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardPreview extends StatefulWidget {   

  final dynamic data;   
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  const CardPreview(this.data, this.onTap);

  CardPreview._(this.data, this.onTap);

  factory CardPreview.fromData(dynamic data, VoidCallback onTap) {
    return new CardPreview(data, onTap);
  }

  CardPreview createState() => new CardPreview(this.data, this.onTap);
}

class CardPreviewState extends State<CardPreview> {   
  final dynamic data;   
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  CardPreviewState(this.data, this.onTap);

  Widget buildCard() {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Ink(
        child: InkWell(
          child: null,
          onTap: () {
            if (this.onTap == null) {
              return;
            }

            this.onTap();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );  
 }

  @override   
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: buildCard(),
    );   
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on Rémi's suggestion of adding a `HitTestBehavior.translucent` behavior to your `GestureDetector`, this is how I would solve your issue:

```
Material(
    child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTapDown: (details) {
            //Do something
        },
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(height: 20.0, width: 20.0, color: Colors.red),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I was able to use something similar to essentially add a `onLongPressStart` and `onLongPressEnd` to my `InkWell`.

Comment: InkWell has onTapDown callback now. But this is still useful to implement onSecondaryTap etc.However, I tested that HitTestBehavior.translucent and HitTestBehavior.opaque has has no impact.

Comment: See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18450#issuecomment-397372078

Answer (score 0):

### InkWell has `onTapDown` callback now

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse/onTapDown.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell/InkWell.html

But, GestureDetector still has more functionality than InkWell, e.g. `onSecondaryTap`. Thus nesting InkWell and GestureDetector is useful today.

### `HitTestBehavior.opaque` has no impact on child-parent relationship

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18450#issuecomment-397372078

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74733#issuecomment-767859584

In short, `HitTestBehavior.opaque` only prevent **sibling behind** it from receiving events by return `true` in HitTest so that its direct parent won't pass on the event to its next child(in reversed order) and return `true` in HitTest.(Thus, sibling behind its ancestors won't receive events as well. Just like that its ancestors' behaviors are overwritten to opaque.) **BUT** its ancestors always **DO** receive events!

Remark: If A is **inside** B(i.e. A is a descendant of B), then B will **never** be **behind** A.

Related source:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox/hitTest.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior/hitTest.html (`RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior` is used by `_RenderColoredBox`, which is the "color" of `Container`)

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior/hitTestSelf.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin/defaultHitTestChildren.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderStack/hitTestChildren.html (Use `defaultHitTestChildren`)

Acknowledgment: heavily refer to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18450#issuecomment-601865975

### For `onTap`, only the callback of the "winner" can fire

See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

> Setting GestureDetector.behavior to HitTestBehavior.opaque or HitTestBehavior.translucent has no impact on parent-child relationships: both GestureDetectors send a GestureRecognizer into the gesture arena, only one wins.

> Some callbacks (e.g. onTapDown) can fire before a recognizer wins the arena, and others (e.g. onTapCancel) fire even when it loses the arena. Therefore, the parent detector in the example above may call some of its callbacks even though it loses in the arena.

This is tricky:

If winner has `onTap` or `onTapDown`, then loser's `onTap` will never fire, and `onTapDown` won't fire if the tap is too short such that gesture arena sweeping happens before `onTapDown` firing.

### InkWell has `onTap` and `onTapDown`

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/468166c713984941c0e5432b7499a1a05a0a0f61/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_well.dart#L1209-L1219

Thus, to achieve best experience, all primary tap callback should be registered on InkWell. Otherwise, if GestureDetector wins, short tap won't trigger splash, else if InkWell wins, short tap won't trigger Gesture's `onTapDown`.