# where i can apply onTap in following code

Tags: android, flutter, dart

how i can apply onTap()

```
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
  child: ListView.builder(
    primary: false,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: categories == null ? 0 : categories.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      Map cat = categories[index];
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(
                cat["img"],
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    // Add one stop for each color. Stops should increase from 0 to 1
                    stops: [0.2, 0.7],
                    colors: [
                      cat['color1'],
                      cat['color2'],
                    ],
                    // stops: [0.0, 0.1],
                  ),
                ),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
              ),
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: 20,
                    minHeight: 20,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      cat["name"],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: Wrap it in a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InkWell and GestureDetector, how to make them work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47297997/inkwell-and-gesturedetector-how-to-make-them-work)

Comment: can you  show how its wrap i am new in flutter .. #Ajil O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){},
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  primary: false,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: categories == null ? 0 : categories.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    Map cat = categories[index];
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.asset(
                              cat["img"],
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  // Add one stop for each color. Stops should increase from 0 to 1
                                  stops: [0.2, 0.7],
                                  colors: [
                                    cat['color1'],
                                    cat['color2'],
                                  ],
                                  // stops: [0.0, 0.1],
                                ),
                              ),
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Container(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                  minWidth: 20,
                                  minHeight: 20,
                                ),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    cat["name"],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Comment: My pleasure! Everything that you can't "tap" on it can be wrapped with a gesture detector. The gesture detector has so many "on tap" properties like on double tap. Check out [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)  . Also accept the answer please if it worked!